# Is there a way to display input prompt text with the index number of array by python?

Tags: python-3.x

Because I want to make user know what numbers he is inputting. I want to display it like this

```
for i in range(0,5):
    V[i]=int(input("Masukkan V ke ",i))
    U[i]=int(input("Masukkan V ke ",i))
```

It doesnt work. Because it doesn't want argument outside of ".."
Is there an alternative way to code it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could cast to `str` then concatenate:

```
... input("Masukkan V ke " + str(i))
```

Or use `print` instead:

```
print("Masukkan V ke", i, end='')
... input()
```

Or use `str.format` or `printf`-style formatting:

```
... input("Masukkan V ke {}".format(i))
... input("Masukkan V ke %s" % i)
```